# CLI installation not working (Missing google_app_id)

Tags: firebase, flutter, command-line-interface, analytics

I've tried to install FlutterFire using CLI, but when I try to use logEvent() in my app, I have the following error:

```
Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
```

I'm almost sure to have perfectly followed the configuration tutorial at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli

Can somebody tell me what is wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to manually install Firebase if you're trying to use Analytics on Android. As stated in the [configuration tutorial](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/):

> Some plugins or platforms do not fully support Dart-only Firebase initialization yet, if you need to use the plugins then the manual installation steps should be followed first.

Analytics, Crashlytics and Performance Monitoring are currently unsupported for Dart-only initialisation. The full list of supported and unsupported platforms for Dart-only initialisation is [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/).

Comment: When will Analytics supported for Dart-only Firebase initialization? For me, only  Dart-only Firebase initialization works, manual initialization has issues. So I am not able use Analytics now

Answer (score 0):

The most recent documentation can be found in [Using the CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#using-the-cli), which says:

> With Dart-only initialization now supported, manually configuring and installing platforms is no longer required.

Also in [Manual Installation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/):

> Manual installation is not the recommended installation flow.

So, it is a bit confusing. I am also dealing with this error and have not fixed it. I also checked "[Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/overview/)" and "[Using Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/usage)" but could not find any references to manual installation.

Comment: Since I do not have enough reputation, I could not comment on @Aliyu Yisa's answer, I had to post. I already know that this is not an answer, thanks.

Comment: When linking to another document use something more descriptive than "this". Summarize where the link is going so people know if they want to click. "[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)" is a good article.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's a bit confusing. As at the time I wrote that, I had to use manual initialisation to be able to use Analytics. The "recommended" way doesn't support all the plugins yet. Also, it seems Analytics is now supported.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `id "com.google.gms.google-services"` to the `app/build.gradle` solved the problem for me.

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}
```